# else statement in angular ng-if

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to figure out how to do an else conditional if any other values are other then the two aleardy present.

```
<p ng-if="item.extras === 'Fun'"><item class="list-number-blue">{{item._id}}</item></p>
      <p ng-if="item.extras === 'Warm up'"><item class="list-number">{{item._id}}</item></p>
<p ng-if="item.extras === ''"><item class="list-number-new">{{item._id}}</item></p>
```

For instance if any value is other than 'Fun' or 'Warm up' to add a different class.  Now I just have '' but I know that can't be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you be able to use 2 conditions and simply reverse the logic?

```
<p ng-if="item.extras === 'Fun'"><item class="list-number-blue">{{item._id}}</item></p>
<p ng-if="item.extras === 'Warm up'"><item class="list-number">{{item._id}}</item></p>
<p ng-if="item.extras !== 'Fun' && item.extras !== 'Warm up'"><item class="list-number-new">{{item._id}}</item></p>
```

More than 2 potential conditions and I'd store the ones you want to not allow as an array and check for an indexof just for maintainability and code cleanliness

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-switch` for if-else condition. The else part can be coded using `ng-switch-default`

```
<div ng-switch='item.extras'>                   
<p ng-switch-when="item.extras === 'Fun'">{{item._id}}</p>
<p ng-switch-when="item.extras === 'Warm up'">{{item._id}}</p>
<p ng-switch-default>{{item._id}}</p>
</div>
```